# Connect to SQL in Java?

Tags: java

I'm having a hard time connecting to a SQL server using Java. Here is my code:

```
package com.C2S.java;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class C2S 
    {


        public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

            try
            {
                Class.forName("com.txfb.bai.jtds.jdbc.Driver");

                String userName = "USEVL01";
                String password = "safevL01";
                String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://TXS9316110MISC;instance=MISC;";

                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);

                Statement sta = conn.createStatement();

                String sql = "select * from OpenQuery(LINKEDDBTP, 'SELECT B.*"
                        + " FROM (SELECT *"
                        + " FROM SFBCDBTP.TXPROD.SUB_AGREEMENT"
                        + " WHERE POL_SYMBOL IN (''HOL'', ''PA6'', ''TXC'')"
                        + " AND TRANS_TYPE = ''NB''"
                        + " AND SUB_AGRMNT_TYPE = ''PL''"
                        + " AND SUB_AGMNT_STATUS = ''A''"
                        + " AND TRANS_EFF_DATE > ''2015-12-31''"
                        + " AND TRANS_EFF_DATE < ''2016-01-16''"
                        + " AND AGREEMENT > 0"
                        + " ORDER BY AGREEMENT"
                        + " FETCH FIRST 300 ROWS ONLY) AS A, TXPROD.COVERAGE_RATES AS B"
                        + " WHERE A.AGREEMENT = B.AGREEMENT"
                        + " AND A.POL_SYMBOL = B.POL_SYMBOL"
                        + " AND A.SUB_AGREEMENT = B.SUB_AGREEMENT;');";

                ResultSet rs = sta.executeQuery(sql);

                while (rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println(rs.getString("txt_title"));
                }


            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("DB Error: " + e);
            }
    }


}
```

When I run the application I get this error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: No message resource found for message property prop.servertype
    at com.txfb.bai.jtds.jdbc.Messages.get(Messages.java:120)
    at com.txfb.bai.jtds.jdbc.Messages.get(Messages.java:67)
    at com.txfb.bai.jtds.jdbc.Driver.parseURL(Driver.java:374)
    at com.txfb.bai.jtds.jdbc.Driver.setupConnectProperties(Driver.java:239)
    at com.txfb.bai.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:182)
    at com.txfb.bai.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:1)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.C2S.java.C2S.main(C2S.java:23)
DB Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: No message resource found for message property prop.servertype

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well, the exception is due to a missing message resource for `prop.servertype`, but the underlying problem is probably an error in the URL.

Comment: The class name for the `jtds` Driver is `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver` http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the name of the JTDS driver to net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver fixed the issue. Thanks to the recommendation from user a-horse-with-no-name!